# Are the big publisher styles copyrighted?

Tags: ieee-style, copyright

Some styles such as IEEE and SIGGRAPH are well thought out, have good citation formatting etc.  If one is to start their own journal, is it possible to use the IEEE style, or are there protections on Latex source files?

Comment: Legal questions are in general off-topic as they are outside of our expertise and as they have answers that are location-dependent.  Here, note that copyright automatically exists on any sufficiently-substantial work: what you can do with source depends on the license conditions.

Comment: as Joseph says it is the licence that you should worry about not copyright. For IEEEtran for example https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/ shows it is LPPL, so you can rename the class then make arbitrary changes and distribute to suit your needs. But you need to check the licence on any class that you copy in such a way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that was what I was looking for.  I see how this could be off topic, but if you put that as an answer for the archives  (other users searching) I would accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a class is licenced under the LPPL (as for example IEEEtran is) then you are allowed to do whatever that allows. The full scope of that is probably a legal question that I'm not qualified to answer, even though I helped to write that licence, but it certainly includes copying the file to a different name, making arbitrary changes and distributing the result under LPPL.